# How do I centre responsive images in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hullo, I have a little "facebook, instagram, twitter" icon thing at the bottom on my website. I can't get the images to centre? Help please!

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid2"><img src="../Website Pic/Capture.PNG" 
alt="Placeholder image" width="90" class="img-responsive-icon"><img 
src="../Website Pic/Capt1ure.PNG" alt="Placeholder image" width="85" 
class="img-responsive-icon"><img src="../Website Pic/f.PNG" alt="Placeholder 
image" width="72" class="img-responsive-icon"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.img-responsive-icon {
display: inline-block;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
float: none;
padding-bottom: 5px;
padding-top: 25px;
max-height: none;
```

Answer (score 1):

The bootstrap method would be to add the class 'text-center'.

```
<div class="container-fluid2 text-center"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.container-fluid2 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

text-align: center to the parent container will do it.

Link here : https://jsfiddle.net/zzzu88ww/

Answer (score 0):

**Try This :**

```
.container-fluid2 {

    text-align: center;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**you can use**

```
text-align: center
.container-fluid2{
 text-align:center;

}
```

Comment: what is different your code with my code? you copy my code.